# Int Autoincrementing Primary Key and GUID column

Tags: sql, frameworks, guid, synchronization

I have an existing database in which the majority of the tables have int primary keys (autoincrementing).

We are now in a position in which we need to now use this db as a central store and allow other clients to connect in and sync data (uploading  / downloading data)

With the primary key being an autoincrementing key I know there is the problem of primary key collision.

So I was thinking I could add a global key to the synced tables - say a GUID.

and then create a custom sync logical looking up this GUID / comparing client

Does this sound like the right idea ? any other suggestions for implementing a sync framework in which very little can be changed on the central database (no primary key changes)

Comment: Generally speaking, an auto-incrementing key will *not* collide; in fact, I'm not sure how to make it happen (since most definitions in SQL include a `Unique` constraint).  You might get `duplicate key` errors, though.  Why are you letting outside vendors dictate what your internal keys are?  Accept a completed record from them, and generate the keys yourself.  If you're running out of keys, increase the size of the column (to a long).  You could generate a new GUID column, yes, but you'd likely still be generating the GUIDs anyways, so what would be the difference?

Comment: Well because they would be in a disconnected environment i.e on mobile devices in which they have their own copy of a subset of their data and the ability to add records - if adding or updating records I would need a means to match up records - the reason for thinking about using the GUID for the matching and syncing process.

Comment: I see where you are going with the 'accept completed record from them' although I still need a matching process - i.e. I need to give the client something back for the record - an ID (cant use an INT as it could collide - as i have 1,000s of potential clients all doing inserts on their own subset and sycning to central db (whilst at the same time the central db is also having inserts done directly on it )

Comment: Often, most tables in a database will have more than one 'unique' key.  These are the 'natural' keys - the actual columns that make up a unique set of data; unfortunately, this may end up being the entire width of the table (which is why `id` columns are used).  Also, unless there is some bizarre use case, don't make the server know about the client ids - make the clients know about the server ids, and keep track of it in a separate column (if necessary).  Then can then have their own internal ids that they use before uploading, that have **no** relation to the keys you give back...

Comment: Sorry confused - what are you saying here? (I know sometimes data will make up more than one unique key - i.e SSN ) dont make the server know about the client ids? confused about this mate? in regard to their own internal IDS yeah they would have either ints autoincremnenting with the GUID being the reference between the client and the server - along with the client ID.

Comment: Sorry, I could have made myself more clear;  It doesn't really matter what your server id is, whether it's `int` based, or a GUID - I'd recommend just sticking with whatever you have, rather than attempting to re-architect something.  Then, instead of forcing the server to know about the client GUIDs, make the client talk to the server using the ids the *server* generated for the inserted row.  This prevents malicious clients from attempting to add already-in-use GUIDs, and related issues (how do you know the GUID they gave you shouldn't have been generated by some *other* device?).

Comment: Ok so basically you are saying allow them to insert on their devices but when it comes to syncing - the sync code will need to get that row or rows and work out if they already exist - if they dont exist then insert into DB and update the GUID ref with whatever the database creates. so the inserts will occur and also the same row will also now have on top of the INT AUTOINCREMENTING id , they will have an GUID which was given to them by the server?

Comment: Exactly, the use the GUID (or an int autoincrementing, whatever the server has for ids) that the server gives them back.  They do *not* get to dictate internal ids on the server.

Comment: why do i not see a option to mark anything as answered?

Comment: Because these are comments on the question, not an answer.  Added as answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking, an auto-incrementing key will not collide; in fact, I'm not sure how to make it happen (since most definitions in SQL include a Unique constraint). You might get `duplicate key` errors, though. Why are you letting outside vendors dictate what your internal keys are? Accept a completed record from them, and generate the keys yourself. If you're running out of keys, increase the size of the column (to a long). You could generate a new GUID column, yes, but you'd likely still be generating the GUIDs anyways, so what would be the difference?

Often, most tables in a database will have more than one 'unique' key. These are the 'natural' keys - the actual columns that make up a unique set of data; unfortunately, this may end up being the entire width of the table (which is why `id` columns are used). Also, unless there is some bizarre use case, don't make the server know about the client ids - make the clients know about the server ids, and keep track of it in a separate column (if necessary) on the client. Then can then have their own internal ids that they use before uploading, that have no relation to the keys you give back - and which they never share with the server.

It doesn't really matter what the server id is (`int` based or a GUID), although I'd recommend sticking with whatever you have.  Whenever the client gives you a row to put on the server, give them back the generated id from the server.  This prevents clients from attempting to insert already-in-use ids, and related issues (how do you know the id they gave you shouldn't have been generated by some other device?). I would say that clients do not get to dictate internal ids on the server

---

EDIT:

In light of some quick research into replication (in response to HLGEM), and re-reading the original question; I initially took the question as asking about letting clients dictate the internal primary keys (which is still bad), and/or replacing the `int` primary keys with the GUID.  Although your exact needs may not require it, adding an extra GUID column that the client can populate would work.  Some recommendations:
1) Treat unique key violations (accidental or malicious) on the GUID column as a *business* exception, not a *system* exception.  I'd probably recommend telling the client to re-generate the GUID and re-submit (silently).
2) The client *never* gets to dictate the acutal primary key column values in the database.  In fact, if you use a GUID column, the client may never even need to know about them.

Comment: I believe they would collide in the scenario given by the OP.

Comment: ... I specifically stated that clients shouldn't get to dictate server ids specifically to *avoid* the colissions.  If they are attempting to re-use unique natural keys, that is a *business* problem, not a *system* one, and should be accounted for as such.

Comment: I entered up working with the Microsoft Sync Framework and adding a column guid to the sync tables along with the existing auto int primary keys' - during sync for the client on the guid's are synced down . this is working really well - the sync framework does the object matching based on the GUID's - whilst existing db code still functions as usual as we still have the auto incre keys

Answer (score 1):

You should look at a replication. I don't know if it will help in your case or not. But replication is generally set up with GUIDs.